# Pandas: randomly select a row based on a group of two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a table like the following:

| id | color | type | category | age | location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | red | civic | single | 21 | california |
| 456 | red | civic | family | 35 | michigan |
| 603 | red | civic | single | 32 | seattle |
| 673 | blue | rav4 | single | 23 | toranto |
| 897 | blue | rav4 | family | 54 | texas |
| 578 | black | rav4 | family | 63 | california |

What I need to do is to keep a random row per each group of color and type. For example, the sample would be something like this:

| id | color | type | category | age | location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | red | civic | single | 21 | california |
| 897 | blue | rav4 | family | 54 | texas |
| 578 | black | rav4 | family | 63 | california |

any idea how this can be achieved?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can do a simple [`.groupby().sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sample.html) and pass in 1 to retrieve a single observation from each group.

```py
print(df.groupby(['color', 'type']).sample(1))
    id  color   type category  age    location
5  578  black   rav4   family   63  california
3  673   blue   rav4   single   23     toranto
0  123    red  civic   single   21  california
```